# Given a summation figure out the alternating series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I figured out that the top is (2x-1) and that the difference between the denominator ends up being (2x-1), just not sure how to figure out what the series is.

[image: alternating series]

Comment: Have you tried finding a quadratic expression for the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the EOIS site, I found the general term for the denominator is $a_n = (n-1)^2+1$, I think you should be able to continue..